# Cannot add or update a child row on the sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbprojeto`.`avaliacao`, CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente_avaliacao` FOREIGN KEY (`cliente`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`idcliente`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I got the above error message when trying to insert some datas in the Data Base. The table has 5 fields, 2 of them are foreign key though. I was told that I have to recover the ids(foreign keys) first so that I could insert correctly. One of the ID's that has to be caught is on the session which is in the JSP page, when users are already logged in. Guess there's nothing wrong with the DAO class once that debug project shows me that is all correct. Might be something with the Servlet I certainly think.

**SERVLET**

```
        try {
        Avaliacao avaliacao = new Avaliacao();
        Prestador prestador = new Prestador();
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        avaliacao.prestador = new Prestador();

        AvaliacaoDAO dao = new AvaliacaoDAO();

        avaliacao.setNota(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nota")));
        avaliacao.setComentario(request.getParameter("comentario"));

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        avaliacao.cliente = (Cliente) session.getAttribute("cliente");

        avaliacao.cliente.setIdcliente(avaliacao.cliente.getIdcliente());
        dao.inserirAvaliacao(avaliacao);
        avaliacao.prestador.setIdprestador(PrestadorDAO.retornarId());

        request.setAttribute("msg", "Gravado com sucesso!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("cadastrado.html").forward(request, response);
```

**DAO Insert method**

```
 public boolean inserirAvaliacao(Avaliacao avaliacao) throws SQLException {
    try {

        Connection conexao = Conexao.getConexao();

        Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();

        String sql = "insert into avaliacao(idavaliacao, nota, comentario, cliente, prestador)values(?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conexao.prepareCall(sql);

        avaliacao.cliente = new Cliente();
        avaliacao.prestador = new Prestador();

        pstmt.setInt(1, avaliacao.getIdavaliacao());
        pstmt.setInt(2, avaliacao.getNota());
        pstmt.setString(3, avaliacao.getComentario());
        pstmt.setInt(4, avaliacao.cliente.getIdcliente());
        pstmt.setInt(5, avaliacao.prestador.getIdprestador());
        pstmt.execute();
        conexao.close();

        return true;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return false;
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        System.out.println(sql);
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Session in the JSP**

```
<%

Cliente cliente = (Cliente) session.getAttribute("cliente");

if (cliente == null) {
    cliente = (Cliente) session.getAttribute("cliente");
}
```

%>

Answer (score 0):

I would say `avaliacao.cliente.getIdcliente());`  returns a value that does not exist in your `cliente` database table.

Comment: This is called Class Relationships.